# WPF slider how to set min/max programmatically?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I tried to set slider min max programmatically but properties are readonly so how can I do this ?

Update: I have made a custom control named slider which encapsulates a slider so he cannot find Maximum and Minimum. That's the reason.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.minimum.aspx does not look read only...

Comment: The properties are definitely not read-only for me.

Comment: I have made a custom control named slider which encapsulates a slider so he cannot find Maximum and Minimum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
slider.Minimum = 0;
slider.Maximum = 10;
```

On an instance `slider`. They are get- and set-able according to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.aspx

Comment: I found why I have made a custom control named slider which encapsulates a slider so he cannot find Maximum and Minimum. That's the reason.